# Next js Axios API integration error (It works in Postman, but the request does not go to the server on localhost)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, cors, next.js13

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://0001.uz/myself' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
> signup.jsx:39 AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
> api.service.js:9

```
   GET https://0001.uz/myself net::ERR_FAILED
```

This is API Service function

```
const AuthService = {
  async getAuth(data) {
    const response = await axios.post("/signup", data);
    return response;
  },
  async getCurrentUser() {
    const response = await axios.get("/myself");
    return response;
  },
};
export default AuthService;
```

and this is Axios config file

```
import axios from "axios";
axios.defaults.baseURL = "https://0001.uz";

axios.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
  config.headers.Key = "Blackmagic";
  config.headers.Secret = "MrBlack";
  config.headers.Sign = "91450883dc60b4d7d63bdb24444cd1bf";
  return config;
});

export default axios;
```

Comment: is it a cross origin request? does the server send CORS headers?

Answer (score 0):

You get a CORS-related error (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) because you attempt to sent a request from http://localhost:3000 to https://0001.uz/myself. This is a safety-measure done by the browser, protecting the target domain from unwelcome requests.

If at https://0001.uz/myself you intend to allow requests from anywhere, then you will need to set it up to return CORS headers, like

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
```

Or, you could make a whitelist for CORS, like:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: [<header-name>[, <header-name>]*]
```

see more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers

The mechanism you would invoke thusly would be to make the target domain send response headers back to the browser so the actual request will be allowed for your origin. Of course, in order for the CORS headers to work, you need them to exist and the origin to comply to them.

Another possibility is to make a copy of the target, host locally and set the CORS headers for it, so you separate your experimental dev environment fully from the target domain via creating a test version of the target.

Finally, you can create your own proxy page where you would direct your requests instead of the target and cURL to the target from this proxy you created.